# What does Kant's universalisable principle have to say on arbitrary rules?

Tags: ethics, kant

> Act only according to that maxim whereby you can at the same time will
>   that it should become a universal law

How does that leave arbitrary rules, and conformity?

If everyone disobeyed, for any reason at all, an arbitrary rule, that I constructed from seeing people behaving as if they were obeying it, would the rule still exist to be disobeyed? If it would not, I wondered if it would fail the universalisability principle, because if everyone disobeyed the rule, no-one would.

How does Kant's ethics cope with that: am I morally obliged to e.g. not disobey a rule *to walk up the street like others have*.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you imply the possibity that in Kantian framework, you may constuct a duty to conformity?

Comment: as an reductio ad absurdum, yes @PhilipKlöcking